# Terraform with GCP fails to create pubsub topic with permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

New to Google Cloud Platform but not to terraform.

Created a service user to manage terraform under the project and gave it `roles/owner`. Created the key for this terraform user.

Terraform code is simple:

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "my_topic" {
  name    = "my_topic"
  project = "${var.project_id}"
}
```

just creating a pub-sub topic.

Terraform plan works but terraform apply gives me:

`google_pubsub_topic.my_topic: googleapi: Error 403: User not authorized to perform this action., forbidden`

I have even tried giving the service account `roles/pubsub.admin` not sure I understand what's going on because my service account has the owner role associated with it yet it can't create a pubsub topic.

Can anybody help me figure this out please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the google pub/sub api doing :

`gcloud services enable pubsub.googleapis.com`